# Python: tile() returns weird error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to do the following:

```
vectors = hstack(((array([[nA, nM, nE]])),
        nP.T,(array([[nM,nA]]))))

tile(P[newaxis, newaxis, newaxis,
        ...,newaxis,newaxis], vectors)
```

However, I get an error message. Following, I've put the output / content of several of the variables in use:

```
# output:
print vectors.shape: (1L, 14L)
print vectors: array([[ 3.,  2.,  5.,  2.,  2.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  2.,  3.]])
print P.shape: (2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L)
print P[newaxis, newaxis, newaxis,
        ...,newaxis,newaxis].shape: (1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L)
tile(P[newaxis, newaxis, newaxis,
        ...,newaxis,newaxis], vectors): ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() (somewhere inside tile())
```

Finally the full Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1050-25019e870a05> in <module>()
      1 P = tile(P[newaxis, newaxis, newaxis,
----> 2     ...,newaxis,newaxis], vectors)

C:\Users\sdaro\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.pyc in tile(A, reps)
    831         tup = (1,)*(c.ndim-d) + tup
    832     for i, nrep in enumerate(tup):
--> 833         if nrep!=1:
    834             c = c.reshape(-1,n).repeat(nrep,0)
    835         dim_in = shape[i]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Its not clear what your question is, but I can comment on the error you're seeing. Obviously, nrep is an array with more than one element. you could try using "if nrep[0]!=1 :", perhaps.

Comment: A simple case producing the same error is: `np.tile(np.ones((2,)),np.array([[1,1]]))`.  The key is that `reps` must be 1d.  `tile` actually converts `reps` to a tuple.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the Python code for `np.tile`?  You can learn about errors, and `numpy` itself by doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a *2D* array (`vectors`) with shape (1,14) as the second argument of `tile`.  Apparently it must be 1D.  Try:

```
tile(P[newaxis, newaxis, newaxis,
        ...,newaxis,newaxis], vectors[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`tile(A, reps)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) wrong.  The second argument, `reps`, is supposed to be a *vector* (one dimensional array) of integers, specifying the number of repetitions along each axis.  Whatever you are passing in (I refuse to try to understand your `vectors` assignment mess)...

```
vectors = hstack(((array([[nA, nM, nE]])),
    nP.T,(array([[nM,nA]]))))
```

...is a multi-dimensional array, so at somepoint numpy will try to treat an element of the array as number, and that fails:

```
# What is x supposed to be?
x = int(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
```